# Does the Docusign REST API have contract forwarding?

Tags: docusignapi

In certain circumstances we would like to automate the forwarding of completed Docusign contracts to certain new recipients, possibly adding another page.  Is there a way to do that with the REST API, or does that have to be done manually?

Comment: Welcome! ***Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is Yes.

In DocuSign-speak, "completed" means that the envelope (transaction) has reached its final stage. No more changes, it's frozen and saved in the DocuSign platform.

Also, note that virtually anything you can do via the DocuSign web app can also be done programmatically via one of DocuSign's APIs.

So you have two options:

### Send the first envelope to someone else as a new envelope

After the first envelope is complete, your API program could analyse it to see if it needs some additional recipients. If so, your API program could start a new envelope transaction that includes the completed (signed) document, possibly the first envelope's certificate of completion, along with the new documents to be signed (or not) and new recipients.

You could include the first set of documents (from the first envelope) either as supplemental documents to the new envelope or as regular documents within the new envelope. To obtain the documents from the first envelope, your application would download them from DocuSign and then upload them for the new envelope.

A live ["supplemental" documents](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=Supplemental%20documents%20in%20four%20styles) example.

### A envelope is optionally sent to additional recipients

An alternative is to have one envelope and optionally programmatically send it to additional signers with, perhaps, additional documents for the new signers.

This might be a bit trickier to program with the DocuSign eSign APIs but is certainly doable.

After the last "original" signer has completed signing, you can [pause](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/pause-workflow/) the workflow.

Once the workflow is paused, your application can again analyse the document to see if more recipients need to sign, an additional document needs to be added, etc. Then your API program uses the API to update the envelope as needed, including adding additional recipients (who may or may not be signers). This is called "correcting" the envelope. Then your program resumes the envelope's workflow.

Your program should be notified that the envelope has paused by using the Connect webhook feature, either at the account or envelope level.

If you have more questions about this answer, please open new questions on StackOverflow. Make each question as specific as you can. Thank you.